# Mott-Bethe electron scattering factor at g=0

Tags: solid-state-physics, scattering, diffraction

I am a non-physicist, but am doing some calculations related to electron diffraction in (crystalline) solids.

Generally, electron scattering factors $f_\text{e}(s)$ can be estimated from the xray scattering factors$f_\text{x}(s)$ by the so-called Mott-Bethe formula:
$$f_{\text{e}}(s)=\frac{1}{8\pi^2 a_{0}}\left[\frac{Z-f_{\text{x}}(s)}{s^2}\right]$$

With $a_0$ the Bohr radius, $Z$ the atomic number, and $s=g/2=\sin\theta/\lambda$. For $s=0$ the problem is clearly ill-defined. Generally $f_\text{e}(0)$ is computed using a separate expression$^1$:
$$f_\text{e}(0)=\frac{4\pi^2m_0e^2}{3h^2}Z\langle r^2\rangle$$

Where $\langle r^2\rangle$ is the mean squared radius of the atom, $m_0$ the rest mass of an electorn, and $e$ the charge of an electron. However I have not been able to correctly compute this particular value, $f_\text{e}(0)$. If I do dimensional analysis of this quantity I get:
$$\left[f_\text{e}(0)\right]=\frac{\text{Kg}\cdot\text{C}^2\cdot\text{m}^2}{\text{J}^2\cdot\text{s}^2}\rightarrow\frac{\text{C}^2}{\text{J}}$$

Which does not have the same units as $[f_\text{e}(s)]=\text{m}$, units of length; nor can I see how it could be reduced to units of length. I assume that I have some basic misunderstanding here that I hope can be pointed out.

$^1$Ibers, J. A. (1958). Acta Cryst. 11, 178-183.